# display error if mail function not working

Tags: php, ajax, email

I'm building an Email verification script and i'm using ajax so whenever the user fill in a false or an invalid email, an error bar with the error name will be displayed, And when the email is true and belongs to an active account, an email will be sent to the user with instructions and the error bar says email sent.
The problem is even the mail function isn't working, the error bar keeps saying email sent.
So i wan't some lines to detect if the email wasn't sent to show "email was not sent" in the error bar.

This is my php file :

```
    <?php 

include '../../app/init.php';

        /* Clean email */
    $recover_email = $_POST['recover_email'];

       /* check if email is valid */
    if(!filter_var($recover_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        /* email not valid */
        echo 3;

        /* Check if email exist */
    } else if(Database::exists('user_id', 'users', ['email' => $recover_email])) {


        /* Define some variables */
        $user_id            = Database::simple_get('user_id', 'users', ['email' => $recover_email]);
        $lost_password_code = md5($recover_email + microtime());

        /* Update the current activation email */
        $database->query("UPDATE `users` SET `lost_password_code` = '{$lost_password_code}' WHERE `user_id` = {$user_id}");

        /* Send the email */
        sendmail($recover_email,  $settings->contact_email, $language->lost_password->email->title, sprintf($language->lost_password->email->content, $settings->url, $recover_email, $lost_password_code));

        /* email exist */
        echo true; 

    } else if(!Database::exists('user_id', 'users', ['email' => $email])) {

        /* email not exist */
        echo false;
    }

?>
```

This is my mail functions :

```
function send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message) {

    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    mail($to, $title, $message, $headers);
}

function sendmail($to, $from, $title, $message) {
    global $settings;

    if(!empty($settings->smtp_host) && !empty($settings->smtp_port) && !empty($settings->smtp_user) && !empty($settings->smtp_pass)) {

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->Host = gethostbyname('tls://'.$settings->smtp_host);
        $mail->Port = $settings->smtp_port;
        $mail->Username = $settings->smtp_user;
        $mail->Password = $settings->smtp_pass;

        $mail->setFrom($from, $settings->title);
        $mail->addReplyTo($from, $settings->title);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->Subject = $title;
        $mail->Body = $message;

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message);
        }

    } else {
        send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message);
    }

}
```

I only need some lines on the php file to return it as a response for the ajax file

Comment: Where does `$email` come from in the third `if` statement? `if...else if...else if($email)`?

Comment: `if (!$mail->send()) {
            // echo "could not send email ";
        }`

Comment: @Anuga the first one wich is inside the if condition is whenever the smtp failed to send email then the last is running always when the smtp configuration is empty

Comment: Well, what your doing, is making it send the mail whenever there is a user. Period. You need to make a `if()` statement on  `mail()` and then return that all the way back to where you call `sendmail()` and have a `if()` statement or `$variable` on that to see if it passed. So this path can be shortened a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`mail()`Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.  So you need to run an if statement to check if the mail was accepted for delivery.

```
<?php

function send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message)
{

    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $title, $message, $headers)) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

function sendmail($to, $from, $title, $message)
{
    global $settings;

    if (!empty($settings->smtp_host) && !empty($settings->smtp_port) && !empty($settings->smtp_user) && !empty($settings->smtp_pass)) {

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->Host     = gethostbyname('tls://' . $settings->smtp_host);
        $mail->Port     = $settings->smtp_port;
        $mail->Username = $settings->smtp_user;
        $mail->Password = $settings->smtp_pass;

        $mail->setFrom($from, $settings->title);
        $mail->addReplyTo($from, $settings->title);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->Subject = $title;
        $mail->Body    = $message;

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            if (!send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message)) {

                echo "Error sending email, please try again later";
            }
        }

    } else {
        if (!send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message)) {

            echo "Error sending email, please try again later";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Anuga you missed this part `if (!send_mail($to, $from, $title, $message)) {`

Comment: Nope, I'm referring to `sendmail()` which is called earlier, not `send_mail()`. His first code snippet. It always `echo true;` after `sendmail()`

Answer (score -2):

just use mail() in if condition and print the appropriate message in if and else block. it will solve the problem

```
if(mail($to, $title, $message, $headers)){
//success message
}
else{
//error message
}
```